# Block Matrix Nonsingular $\iff v^T A^{-1} u\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination, transpose

Here is the given question and my work so far:

**Question:** Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ invertible matrix, and let $u$ and $v$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Find the necessary and sufficient conditions on $u$ and $v$ in order that the matrix
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
A & u\\[1ex]
v^T & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
be invertible, and give a formula for the inverse when it exists.

**Solution:** Performing block Gaussian elimination on $B$, specifically $R_2-v^T A^{-1}R_1\longrightarrow R_2$, we obtain

$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
A & u\\[1ex]
0 & -v^TA^{-1}u
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Next, recall that in order for a matrix to be nonsingular, it is both necessary and sufficient that its determinant be nonzero. Before we proceed, take note of the fact that from $(-v^T A^{-1} u)$ we produce $(1\times n) \cdot (n\times n) \cdot (n\times 1) = 1\times 1$. Thus, the product produces a scalar.

Now, we wish to show that $\det(B)\neq 0$. Then,

$$\det (B) = \det (A\cdot -v^T A^{-1} u)=(-v^T A^{-1} u)\cdot \det(A) $$

Because $A$ is nonsingular, we know that $\det(A)\neq 0$ and moreover, that $A^{-1}u\neq0$ for $u\neq 0$.

**My Question:** How do I show that $v^T A^{-1} u\neq 0$?

Comment: The matrix is invertible *if and only if* $v^TA^{-1}u\ne0$. Do Laplace expansion on the last row.

Comment: @egreg Wouldn't that just produce what I already have? Namely, $\det (B) = \det (A\cdot -v^T A^{-1} u)=(-v^T A^{-1} u)\cdot \det(A) $

Answer (score 1):

You did everything right (up to the computation of the determinant, which is not written down correctly). Doing Laplace expansion on the last row,
$$
\det B=(-v^TA^{-1}u)\det A
$$
so this is nonzero if and only if $v^TA^{-1}u\ne0$.

You can't prove that $v^TA^{-1}u\ne0$, because it's false in general (think to $u=0$, for instance), but the question was asking precisely to show an “if and only if” statement.

Comment: Ok. From the given question "Find the necessary and sufficient conditions on $u$ and $v$ such that $B$ is invertible". Would stating that $v^T A^{-1} u\neq 0$ be the nasc? The only reason I'm feeling apprehensive about that is because it involves $A^{-1}$.

Comment: @hungryformath You can't really say more than that: in terms of the inner product, this means $v$ is not orthogonal to $A^{-1}u$, so the condition does depend on $A$.